# index.php appending to url

Tags: apache, magento

I have a magento site which has index.php appended to the url you click on. I googled a lot to find the solution and i did what i could find.To clear my my doubts i uploaded htaccess file fresh copy from magento copy and made the url rewrite in configuation>system>web to yes and clear the cache too but still it put index.php in url.I have also double checked secure and unsecure link to see if it contain any index.php which it doesn't
 I can do all what i can to do research and applied it but no change. What can i do or what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you describe should be right:

- *System > Configuration > Web > Use Web Server Rewrites* set to yes (also check the store view level value, because the scope for this is not global)
- .htaccess present in document root
- clear Magento cache

Additional things to check:

- *System > Configuration > Web > (Un)secure base url*
- does your Apache take into consideration .htaccess (AllowOverride)
- how did you clear the cache
- the scope for your settings *System > Configuration > Web > Use Web Server Rewrites*

Comment: it worked! it was the scope problem. i really don't understand scopes and what they are but it helped. thanks a lot!